# Angular 6.x / Set jsessionid cookie

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth, jsessionid, angular-http-interceptors

I developed my app backend using java and springboot 2.x, and in the other hand I have my angular app. I also use the OAuth2 protocol to log in, and what I need is to save the JSESSION id google provides after logging in a cookie so then send it in every request to the backend app. I read about using HttpInterceptor but I can not work it out. 
Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Angular HTTPInterceptor is the most appropriate solution**.

You can use it applying the following steps:

1: **Build your HTTPInterceptor** (an @Injectable service):

```
@Injectable()
export class SpringbootInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // Clone the request to add the new header
    const clonedRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Set-Cookie', 'jsessionid=' + this.auth.getJSessionId()) });

    // Pass control to the next request
    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }
}
```

Note that **.clone()** method add info provided as params.

2: **Set Interceptor to your NgModule providers**:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: SpringbootInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

Now, any request from your NgModule, set headers in **SpringbootInterceptor**.

You can check more info at:

- https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor
- https://angular.io/api/http/Headers

Comment: Where can import this? auth: AuthService

Comment: Clarifying **constructor(public auth: AuthService){}**. AuthService typically store User Info (name, **sessionToken**, other configs . . .). I update my answer. Check it!

Comment: I understand what you mean but I can't import that class, should I create it or import it from any library or something?. I googled it but people use that class with firebase, but i have no idea about that.

Comment: Ok, step by step. Where do you store your jsessio id token?

Comment: That's my problem. I want to store the JSESSIONID token from angular after I log in but I can't .

Comment: Can you update your question with copy/paste of your http request? :)

Comment: I finally got it! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you please share the code how you get the JSESSIONID from token?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Solution :

```
constructor(public restProvider: RestProvider) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (this.restProvider.getToken() != null) {
    const clonedRequest = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
    });
  }
}
```