# Reading JESSIONID cookie in Angular 6

Tags: angular, cookies

I am working on a sample application with Spring Boot and Angular 6
I am using spring security with form based login

I am facing below issue while authentication

1)User gets authenticated using form based login and returns `JSESSIONID` in cookie

2)When the next request is sent by browser , the `JSESSIONID` cookie is **NOT SENT** in request causing cookie based authentication failure

After searching a bit , I have found  [Angular 6.x / Set jsessionid cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601358/angular-6-x-set-jsessionid-cookie) answer which uses `HttpInterceptor` to send `JSESSIONID` cookie in request.

But my question is : How to read `JSESSIONID` cookie at first place ? 
Do we need to write any service for this ?

Apart from above approach , we can use `{withCredentials = true}` approach , but it requires to be added in every request in code which seems not an efficient solution.

Is any other approach available to solve this issue ?

Please help

Comment: I can't answer, but for reference: the JSESSIONID cookie will (should) be marked httpOnly, meaning it can't be gotten programmatically - it can only be attached to a response by the browser, which does so automatically. If it isn't being attached that's a different problem. If you want to go about it this way, you will need the 'withCredentials' thing, which can be added in an interceptor to minimize impact on the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. When there is successful authentication, you have to get the JSESSIONID from backend and try to store that JSESSIONID in the sesisonStorage (a STORAGE variable).
2. Next, as you said, we need Interceptor for sure because for the next HTTP request on wards we need to set this JSESSIONID and need to trigger the rest service.
3. So you have to write an sample interceptor service which intercepts during an HTTP call and this point get the sessionId stored in STORE and set this JSESSIONID and trigger the HTTP request. you would able to hit successfully.

I can give you sample example, we are using JWT authentication
1. during login(), am getting the Bearer toke and setting in session storage. (with encrypted format.)
2.I have written and interceptor as shown below:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let token= JSON.parse(this.store.getStoreItem('token'));
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
    return next.handle(request);    
}
```

3. The above store is the local variable for the Store service. 
   Please take this as reference in case: https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/use-localstorage-sessionstorage-using-webstorage-angular4/

Thanks and Regards,
Kishore Kumar. K

Comment: Thanks Kishore. But my question is how to get and store JSESSIONID at first place (Point no. 1 in your explanation)